# How can i show text over border with css

Tags: html, css

I am creating HTML and CSS with this design proposal:
[image: design]

But my result is:

[image: my html]

**HTML code:**

```
<div className="project_content">
  <div className="project_quick f_bold" id="tab">
    <a><span>업데이트</span><span className="alral_num">1</span></a>
    <a><span>커뮤니티</span><span className="alral_num">34</span></a>
    <a><span>통계</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.alral_num {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px 7px 0 7px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #e8351d;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
 .project_content .project_quick .alral_num {
    position:relative;
    width: 20px;
    display: table;
    left: 20%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
 .project_quick a {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 20px 40px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: url(../../assets/images/line01.gif) no-repeat right 50%;
}
 .project_quick a:last-child{
    background: none
}
 .f_bold {
    font-weight: 700 !important;
}
```

**I want to show numbers over border**

I have tried `position:fixed`, But i have to scroll vertically or horizontally, and the numbers should be moved when it scrolls. so it didn't work.

Comment: Seems like you have somewhere `overflow: hidden` in your CSS.

Comment: There is a overflow-x:auto; I changed it to overflow-x:inherit then it works. Thank you for your comment